# Using negation operator ! with std::atomic<uint_32>

Tags: c++, atomic, boolean-operations

I have a working piece of code:

```cpp
#include <atomic>
#include <cstdint>


int main()
{
    std::atomic<uint32_t> foo;

    foo = 5;
    std::cout << foo.load() << std::endl;

    if (!foo) // what is checked here????????????
    {
        std::cout << "!foo == TRUE\n";
    }
    else
    {
        std::cout << "!foo == FALSE\n";
    }


    return 0;
}

// Output : 
// 5
// !foo == FALSE
```

There is no `bool` operator on cppreference for `std::atomic` and CLion doesn't show it as operator. What is checked in `if`-condition?

Comment: There's no `!` operator for `atomic`, it just performs an implicit conversion to the underlying type first.

Comment: see: https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/atomic/atomic/operator_T

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What it is trying to do is convert it to a boolean value so that it can determine which block to run.
Because 5 is a 'truthy' value, it is converting it to `true`, and then negating that to `false`. On the other hand, 0 is a 'falsy' value, so it becomes `false` negated to `true`.